# PagingPredicate issues with comparator

Tags: sorting, pagination, paging, hazelcast, predicate

PagingPredicate when applied on IMap not sorting on the complete collection. It is only sorting for the given pageSize. But I want the collection to be sorted first and then apply the paging and provide the result.

I use below constructor:

```
PagingPredicate pagingPredicate = new PagingPredicate(predicate, comparator, 100);
Collection<Map<String, Object>> pagingResults = data.values(pagingPredicate);
```

The data which is in the cache is almost 90000 records. I need first 100 records from complete sorted collection but it is applying sorting on first 100 records in IMap

Please, can you help in resolving this issue?

hazelcast version - 3.7.3

Answer (score 2):

PagingPredicate internally sorts all the records. Hazelcast keeps the records partitioned. The sorting happens on each partition and top 100 records is selected. So for 271 (default) partition you will have 27100 records on your local. These records will be merged and sorted again, and the resulting top 100 records will be returned.

For example if you have 1-90000 records, paging-predicate should return 1-100 for pagingSize=100.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ali.
I am running on single node and the IMap holds almost 90000 records. When I use PagingPredicate with greater pageSize the results were sorted with pagination support. But when pageSize given as 100 or 200 and try get the 1st page (ZERO) then it was not providing proper results.

Comment: here is a test https://gist.github.com/gurbuzali/09129fe9878199254344d55e1360baa2